# I need a function to have normal parameter, default value parameter and *args, how can I skip providing a value for the default value argument?

Tags: python, function

I tried this but it didn't work at all:

```
def f(x, q='me', *y, **z):
    print(x)
    print(q)
    print(y)
    print(z)

f('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', m=9, n=10)
```

I want it to be as follows:

- `x = 1`
- `q = 'me'`
- `y = ('2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8')`
- `z = {'m': 9, 'n': 10}`

Comment: Switch the order of parameters to `def f(x, *y, q='me', **z,)`

Comment: what the hell man, it worked, thanks i really appreciate it

Comment: You have to specify positional parameters before keyword parameters because the keyword is actually optional.  If you define a function `def f(x, y=None)` both `f(1, y=2)` and `f(1, 2)` work and do the same thing.

Comment: note that this makes `q` a "keyword only" parameter (i.e. to override default value you'd have to pass `q=something`) which is fine as there's no other way it could work